# Get a return value from Electron's webContents.executeJavaScript with NodeIntegration disabled - Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron

I know when [NodeIntegration](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md) is on, you can potentially use ipcRenderer. Is there anything at all you can do to get a return value without NodeIntegration?

Answer (score 0):

`executeJavascript` have return value:

> Returns Promise - A promise that resolves with the result of the
>   executed code or is rejected if the result of the code is a rejected
>   promise.

that value of your function execution result. You can't get non-serializable results still though.

Comment: reference: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback

Comment: I'm trying to get the `innerHTML` value of an element on a page, but this does not seem to be do-able with the result that this produces.

In the example shown the returned value does not come from the page running the Javascript.

Comment: how do you able to get `innerHTML` via ipc? afaik it's non-serializable that you can't send via ipc as well. Moreover, if you need to send innerHTML to other processes, I'd recommend rearchitect code flow to not to those - fundamentally all process communication is based on platform specific process communication comes with a cost for large blob / frequent exchange.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can get innerHTML with something simple like: `mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('    document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML;');` You just can't get the value out of the page with it...

Comment: @Slbox You can with this: `contents.executeJavaScript(\`
      function getTest() {
        return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
      }
      getTest()
    \`).then((ans) => {
      console.log(ans)
    })`